# How to change modal background in react-native-picker-select?

Tags: react-native-picker-select

I want to try changing the background color of modal from white to black. that's because I'm implementing the dark mode and light mode features

Comment: Can you share some code so that we know how you have defined your picker?

Comment: Event found a solution?